# I can't figure out what's going on with PHP?

Tags: php, mamp

I have my site directory on my previous laptop with MAMP installed and everything is displaying properly. I switched into a MacBook Pro not too long ago, had MAMP set up on my machine like normal, and for some reason that same page that works perfectly fine on my old machine is not displaying on my new laptop.

• I have PHP 5.6.24 installed on both laptops, so I figured it wasn't PHP.
• I have the same MAMP installed, but it doesn't seem to be the issue. 
• I checked to see if PHP works so added an echo "testing"; and it shows "testing" on the page. 
• I tried an echo "testing"; on the @include files, and those show up as well. 
• I'm on macOS Sierra version 10.12.2 on my new laptop and version 10.12 on my old laptop, but I doubt that could be the problem.

I'm not sure what is going on, is there any other info that would help you guys to figure out what's going on with my new machine? Thank you so much.

Comment: Forget about the differences between the machines for a minute and focus specifically on the problem itself.  You have PHP code that isn't working.  We don't know what that code is or what "isn't working" about it.

Comment: are you using a framework? have you checked your error log?